# Transition Code

Tags: jquery, transition

I have one question about Transition Code. I was generate something like that by Jssor generator

```
{$Duration:4000,x:-1,y:0.7,$Delay:80,$Cols:12,$Clip:11,$Move:true,$During:{$Left:[0.35,0.65],$Top:[0.35,0.65],$Clip:[0,0.1]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:2049,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutJump,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad},$ScaleClip:0.7,$Round:{$Top:4}}
```

and I'm still didn't find a answer where I have to put inside this code. Anybody that can help me? I want to have same slider like here http://www.jssor.com/slideshow/x-compound.html.

And here is my HTML code

```
    <body style="background-image: url(IMG_1411.jpg); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>

<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {

                $AutoPlay: true,                                   //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $DragOrientation: 1                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)



                        };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        });
    </script>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Java scripts and another files is in right place.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the options for the library. See their examples in [documentation](http://www.jssor.com/development/)

For instance, [this example of Slider with Slideshow](http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-no-jquery.html)

```
<script src="jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        //Define an array of slideshow transition code
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        { code1 },
        { code2 },
        { code3 }
        ];
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                    $ShowLink: true
                }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    };
</script>
```

[Here](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html) are all the options available, please notice that not all of them seem to be documented